# How to explain that we stopped giving out cards for the day?

Tags: phrases, word-usage

My restaurant uses a queue card (or ticket, I'm not sure what they're called) system.

Question is, how should I say when I want to let my customers know that our restaurant stopped giving queue cards for today (due to 300+ queue cards being distributed that day or other reasons)?

Comment: Although, answers are somewhat opinion-based and your question probably will be closed, you can simply say **No more queue cards today!**.

Comment: Although this is not a subject much discussed in the world, I believe the type of system to which you refer is commonly known as a "Deli System" (at least here in the UK) because (here) it was first employed at the Delicatessen counter in supermarkets. Here, at least, the tokens are called "tickets".

Comment: I have always known this system as a "take-a-number system".  Maybe you could tell them that "we have reached capacity for today".  Incidentally, in programming a queue is referred to as "FIFO", or "first in, first out".  In contrast, a stack is known as "LIFO", or "last in, first out".

Comment: How about "We're sold out for today."

Answer (score 2):

Formally: "No more/further queue tickets will be dispensed today".
Informally: "Sorry guys, that's the end of the queue tickets."

There are probably a million ways to go about saying that.

Comment: I would even go with something as simple as, "That's it for today, come back tomorrow."

Comment: +1 for the "formal" phrasing.  Be as clear and correct as possible.  Don't be abrupt or rude.  Saving ink/space/time/syllables is not a high priority here.  NO TALK LIKE CAVE MAN.

Answer (score 0):

NO CUSTOMER TICKETS ISSUED AT THIS TIME

The customer queue is full to capacity for today.  We welcome your patronage another day, and apologize for the inconvenience.

Comment: "NO CUSTOMER TICKETS ISSUED AT THIS TIME" is bad phrasing, as it might be interpreted to mean "no customer tickets _have been_ issued" rather than "no customer tickets _will be_ issued".

Comment: @DougWarren - Perhaps you would like this better: NO MORE CUSTOMER TICKETS ISSUED TODAY.